# matplotlib is throwing segmentation fault when running on non-gui machine(web server)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to save images without showing plotted images when using marplotlib library. Here is the sample example which I have been trying out for a while now.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('temp.jpg', format='jpg', bbox_inches=extent, pad_inches=0)
```

But I am getting this error,

```
The program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

I used gdb tool to debug, where went wrong.. Then I can see this error log...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
copy_hline (c=..., len=27822, y=19297, x=0, this=0x364f9a8) at  extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_pixfmt_rgba.h:1741
1741    extern/agg24-svn/include/agg_pixfmt_rgba.h: No such file or directory.
```

I have no idea why this is happing. Any help on this really appreciated.

I am using matplotlib '1.5.3'.

Comment: Have you tried other backends? Or saving to png/pdf and converting that as a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update this. After installing matplotlib 2.0.0. The problem has been resolved. Thank you for trying to help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, by upgrading matplotlib library to 2.0.0.

```
pip install matplotlib==2.0.0
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, don't forget to accept your answer in 2 days:)